# $Ax\le b$ has a solution if $[I, -A$, $ A]x'=b$ has a non-negative solution $x'$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$Ax\le b$ has a solution if $[I, -A$,  $ A]x'=b$ has a non-negative solution $x'$

Could you please explian this statement.

Let $A$ be a matrix

and $b$ be a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write $x'$ as a block vector $x' = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$, then we find
$$
[I,-A,A]x' = x_1 - Ax_2 + Ax_3 = x_1 + A(x_3 - x_2)
$$
Now, suppose that $[I,-A,A]x' = b$ has a non-negative solution.  Then there are non-negative vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3$ such that
$$
x_1 + A(x_3 - x_2) = b
$$
That is, if we set $x = x_3 - x_2$, then we find
$$
b - Ax = x_1 \geq 0
$$
Thus, $x = x_3 - x_2$ is a solution to the equation $Ax \leq b$.